# Retrieving Currently Logged In User From Dajax Function

Tags: django, dajaxice

I'm currently using a dajaxice call in a template, and I'd like to be able to retrieve the currently logged in user within the python function my dajax calls.

I know that the dajax passes a 'request' parameter to the python function which contains the session ID, but I've had no luck ascertaining the type of variable 'request' is. I've tried converting it to a string, decoding it as a JSON string, and multiple other methods.

All I'd like to be able to do is find the currently logged in user within the python function which dajax calls, without passing it in from the actual template, as that's unreliable security-wise.

A broken down version of my relevant code:

Dajax Call:

```
Dajaxice.fortura_test.rbac_test(rbac_callback,{});
```

rbac_test():

```
@dajaxice_register
def rbac_test(request):
    import re;
    from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    request_string = str(request);
    request_list = [];
    for x in request_string:
        request_list.append(x);
    request_string = ''.join(request_list);
    m = re.match(r"'sessionid'\: '([A-Za-z0-9]+)'",request_string);
    if m is not None:
        session_key = m.group(0);
        session = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)
        uid = session.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id')
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
        return user.id
    else:
        return 'No match';
```

The method above I'm currently using doesn't quite work, but I feel like there should be a better way than how I'm approaching this at the moment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is a normal Django view then `request` is Django's [HTTPRequest object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) and you can get the currently logged in user using `request.user` which will return a [`contrib.auth.models.User`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#methods) instance (you can make sure they are logged in by using `request.user.is_autenticated()`)

Comment: You're spot on. To retrieve the user ID all I need to do is return request.user.id -- I could have sworn I tried doing this in the first place. I eventually found this out by debugging the app today. Perhaps another bug was getting in the way at the time. Thanks for the answer.